# Timestamp.UTCNow is not up to date

Tags: c#, datetime, timestamp

I have created a simple class which gets the Unix timestamp. The first time it is called it returns the timestamp, but after then it always returns the same value it returned the first time, like it has been cached.

What is going on here?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class Timestamp {    
    public static float now {
        get {
            return (float)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime (1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
        }
    }    
}
```

Timestamp.now always returns the same value

Edit:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;


    public static float now {
        get {
            Debug.Log(DateTime.UtcNow); // 1
            Debug.Log(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract (new DateTime (1970, 1, 1))); // 2
            float ts = (float)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract (new DateTime (1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
            Debug.Log(ts.ToString("F")); // 3
            return ts;
        }
    }

}
```

1) printed 5/8/2016 11:44:57 PM at the first call, and 5/8/2016 11:45:05 PM at second call, so it is up to date

2) printed 16929.23:44:57.2918073 at first call and 16929.23:45:05.9735794 at second call, so it is up to date

3) always printed 1462751000.00

Comment: The method `Subract` of `DateTime.UtcNow` returns a `TimeSpan`, you have casted it to a `float` which is incorrect.

Comment: Why do you convert the result into a `float`?

Comment: @t0mm13b The value of the `TotalSeconds` property is being cast, which has type `double` and can be converted to `float`.

Comment: With current Unix time, `float` type have resolution of 128 seconds. You need to wait more then two minutes to guaranty observe value change.

Comment: @PetSerAl has the correct answer. Change it to `double now` and remove the cast to float, you will observe the value changing much more quickly.

Comment: @PetSerAl will try now

Comment: @Pixel - Do you know you can use `DateTimeOffset` (which is the updated version of `DateTime` to do this: `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (as pointed out in the comments by @PetSerAl) is that `float` has too limited precision.

Observe:

```
var nowAsDouble = (DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime (1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
var nowAsFloat = (float)nowAsDouble;

Console.WriteLine("double: " + nowAsDouble.ToString("0.0"));
Console.WriteLine("float:  " + nowAsFloat.ToString("0.0"));
```

Output:

> ```
> double: 1462751469.2  
> float:  1462751000.0
> ```

If you run this several times, you'll see the double version changing every time, where the float value is always truncated.

You need to use `double` values instead of `float`.

Comment: Ok now i understand! It was better to take the double and eventually convert it to int ( i am actually doing that now) than converting to a float because it loses floating point resolution .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static int now {
        get {
            return (int)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract (new DateTime (1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
        }
    }
```

Comment: he casted TotalSeconds and it's a double, so it can be casted to float

Comment: have you guys tried before you vote, try that out and check the value at http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

Comment: Pretty sad when the only correct answer gets downvoted so heavily, the Unix timestamp is indeed *int*.  Come on people, don't just assume that the OP knows what he's doing.  He doesn't.